# GWT Session Singleton

Tags: java, session, gwt, singleton

In GWT I want to store an Object on the server that contains session configuration.
It has to be on the server side.

I tried to create a static instance of the object within my RPC implementation however it seems that is a true Singleton and the same configuration appears for all users. Any idea how I can tackle this? The configuration is passed to the sever from the client using RPC. I want to store this on the server till the client closes their browser.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I finally got my googling right...

In the RPC Implementation:

Set

```
    HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);  
    httpSession.setAttribute("connectionConfig", connectionConfig);
```

Get

```
    HttpSession httpSession = getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true);  
    ConnectionConfig config = (ConnectionConfig) httpSession.getAttribute("connectionConfig");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many ways to do this & this tightly depends on you application. I thinks you can directly store your object as a session object & this is easiest way, but if you dont want to do this for any reason, another suggestion is to create a static hashmap, & put objects on that & using user session ID as key of this hashmap.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ehsan, but the trouble with your approach is that once a session is terminated, the object will persist and eventually use up all the memory. Unless I'm missing something.